# After I call a service my view does not get updated in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have the following service:

```
angular.module('adminApp')
.factory('subjectService', function ($http) {
    return {
        get: function (testAccountId) {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/api/Subjects/GetSelect',
                params: { testAccountId: testAccountId }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The following code works when I call http directly but now when I use the service:

```
    $scope.$watch('selectedTestAccount', function () {
        if ($scope.selectedTestAccount != null) {
            $scope.myData = null;

            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/api/Subjects/GetSelect',
                params: { testAccountId: $scope.selectedTestAccount }
            }).success(function (result) {
                $scope.subjects = result;
                $scope.myData = null;
            });

            //subjectService.get($scope.selectedTestAccount)
            //    .then(function (result) {
            //        $scope.subjects = result;
            //        $scope.myData = null;
            //        alert($scope.subjects);
            //    }, function (result) {
            //        alert("Error: No data returned");
            //    });
        }
    });
```

Related to this question. Is this the correct way to call the service. I saw another suggestion that looked like the following and used promises. Should I be doing this:

```
services.factory('MultiRecipeLoader', ['Recipe', '$q',
   function(Recipe, $q) {
      return function() {
         var delay = $q.defer();
         Recipe.query(function(recipes) {
            delay.resolve(recipes);
         }, function() {
            delay.reject('Unable to fetch recipes');
         });
         return delay.promise;
      };
}]);
```

Comment: could you share fiddle or plunker demo

Comment: Hello Ajay. I'm not sure I can create one as I use http to get data. I guess a key thing here is that the data does seem to get retrieved as I can see it in the result that's returned when I use the debugger. I also see it in the $scope. It's just the view does not change.

Comment: $http also returns a promise so your first example also returns a promise

Comment: @Ajaybeni - I updated the question with an example that works. The code looks the same if I have it in the controller or the service. But the service call does not change my select list that's populated by $scope.subjects while it does work in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your exemple in a plunker. Let me know if it is what you are look for:

http://plnkr.co/edit/6s5utccjgHTnrrokM1u8?p=preview

In this demo, there is a dropdown that changes the value of the **account** variable that is **$watched** in the  controller. If the account value changes, it calls the SubjectsServices and updates the unordered list with the names of the subjects. As an addition, there is also a dropdown filled with the same values.

If the only way to change the value is through the dropdown, maybe you can only use the **ng-change** directive on the select to call an update function that will do the same work.

```
$scope.update = function() {
    SubjectService.get($scope.account).then(function(result) {
        $scope.subjects = result.data;
    }, function(result) {
        // error handling...
    }); 
};

<select ng-change="update()"></select>
```

The object received in parameter from the method **then** on an **$http** promise has a data property containing the requested data.

```
$http.get(...).then(function(result) {
    var subjects = result.data;
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to create a plnkr.  This solution works and is similar to what I need. But I want to somehow return a promise so that in the controller so I can check if it worked or not. I updated my question with a suggestion I found. Should I perhaps use $q in my service if I want to use .then in my controller?

Comment: The $http.get already returns a promise that you can use with chaining the *success* and *error* methods or use *then* with two functions as parameters to do the same.

Comment: I tried calling http from the controller and it worked. But when I call from the service it still does not work. I updated my question. I'm confused why it does not work when I use the service. Thanks for your suggestion about update()

Comment: I have edited the plunker with a $http request in the service.

Comment: I found out what is wrong. I have changed my code to: $scope.subjects = result.data;  Now it works. Thanks for all your help. Can you update your answer so you get the credit and so others can clearly see the problem and answer.  What helped me to see the problem was that you used console to log the data returned.